# cProfile - How can I find specific accesses of thread lock variables?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cprofile

I am profiling my program with `python -m cProfile script.py`.

I am using multiprocessing and it seems that the program is taking a lot of time accessing thread lock variables, because the top of cProfile is:
`method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects`

How can I know in the code where those specific accesses happened?

Comment: I have same problem. It seems cProfile can not analysis the methods inside the thread.